# How to add uinavigation controller to tabbar based application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i am making a tabbar based app, but the problem is I have several views like login view and a tableview that has to be shown before the tabbar view. My problem is if take a tabbar based application it doesn't have a navigation controller, so when I want to push the another viewcontroller from the tableview controller it is not possible. The flow of my app would be:

first screen loginview -> TableView (rootviewcontroller) -->tabbar View.

I am adding the loginview from appdelegate using addSubviewmethod. Then from LoginViewController I do the following :

```
myAppDelegate *appDel=(myAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[aapDel.view addSubview:myTableViewController.view];
```

Now if I want to push something from the myTableViewcontroller it does not respond. Moreover there is no navigation bar on the mytableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, the easiest way here is to add `UINavigationController` to the main window (`UIWindow`). And hide it on the first screens? And then you can use `self.navigationItem` and `self.navigationController` in you code (from any view controller, pushed to UINavigationController) to push/pop other ViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your own navigationController =)

Comment: thnx.i already did that. i was doing somethng wrong somewhere so it wasnt working the way i wanted. now everythngs fine